# Analyzing a specific style of element in Browser

Tags: css, debugging, browser

I want to watch a specific style of element.
For example, I want to analyze background-color of a element.
I want to know which the color of it comes from, for instance, a class, a id, or parent attribute.
In Chrome, I can see its all styles by Right-click element and "Inspect element".
However it has too many styles, so I have difficulty finding aimed information.
Is there a way to view only a specific style with parent information of a element?

Comment: you can right click on that particular element and say inspect element and it shows you that particular style

Answer (score 1):

When viewing styles in chrome, click the "Computed Style" tab to view only the current, actual style properties.